# Is it possible to filter nuget packages by supported platform?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

For example, if I want only packages for [.Net Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md). Now I am looking for a package, try to install it, getting:

```
error: Package <name> is not compatible with netcoreapp1.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0). 
Package <name> supports: portable-win81+wpa81 (.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile32)
error: One or more packages are incompatible with .NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0.
```

and I have to start again. I see the supported platforms. That means, the info is there.

Edit: It will be better if I can set a filter in Visual Studio, but I do not see such, I have not seen it in nuget.org too. So the question is: Is there a way to get packages only for certain platform (that means filter by platform search for something). What I am interested in is .Net Platform Standard. I hope, you do not see something vague here.

Edit: 
[Here is the search api](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/$metadata) from nuget.org

```
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">
    <edmx:DataServices xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" m:DataServiceVersion="2.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="2.0">
        <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm" Namespace="NuGetGallery.OData">
            <EntityType Name="V2FeedPackage" m:HasStream="true">...</EntityType>
        </Schema>
        <Schema xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2006/04/edm" Namespace="NuGetGallery">
            <EntityContainer Name="V2FeedContext" m:IsDefaultEntityContainer="true">
                <EntitySet Name="Packages" EntityType="NuGetGallery.OData.V2FeedPackage"/>
                <FunctionImport Name="Search" ReturnType="Collection(NuGetGallery.OData.V2FeedPackage)" EntitySet="Packages">
                    <Parameter Name="searchTerm" Type="Edm.String" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false"/>
                    <Parameter Name="targetFramework" Type="Edm.String" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false"/>
                    <Parameter Name="includePrerelease" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
                </FunctionImport>
                <FunctionImport Name="FindPackagesById" ReturnType="Collection(NuGetGallery.OData.V2FeedPackage)" EntitySet="Packages">
                    <Parameter Name="id" Type="Edm.String" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false"/>
                </FunctionImport>
                <FunctionImport Name="GetUpdates" ReturnType="Collection(NuGetGallery.OData.V2FeedPackage)" EntitySet="Packages">
                    <Parameter Name="packageIds" Type="Edm.String" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false"/>
                    <Parameter Name="versions" Type="Edm.String" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false"/>
                    <Parameter Name="includePrerelease" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
                    <Parameter Name="includeAllVersions" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false"/>
                    <Parameter Name="targetFrameworks" Type="Edm.String" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false"/>
                    <Parameter Name="versionConstraints" Type="Edm.String" FixedLength="false" Unicode="false"/>
                </FunctionImport>
            </EntityContainer>
        </Schema>
    </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

When I use [Search function](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/Search()?searchTerm='MVVM'&targetFramework='netstandard'&$top=10), the 'searchTerm' parameter works, but not the 'targetFramework' parameter.

Another Edit: VisualStudio NuGet HTTP request in Fiddler:

```
GET /api/v2/Search()?$filter=IsAbsoluteLatestVersion&searchTerm='mvv'&targetFramework='netcoreapp1.0'&includePrerelease=true&$skip=0&$top=26 HTTP/1.1
```

The target framework is set automatically from Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager. What actually does not work is the targetFramework parameter in the search api from NuGet

Comment: finding them locally, on nuget.org or during build? Would love to get my first bounty, but the question is a bit vague ;)

Comment: @Thomas no reason an answer can't include all three! Making it applicable to a wider audience only increases your chances at a shiny gold badge or two ;)

Answer (score 8):

NuGet has option to target the framework as mentioned in [here](http://blog.nuget.org/20141001/targetframeworkfiltering.html)

There is an open feature request matching your scenario [on github](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/issues/2936)

I feel there might a possibility to attain your filtering using power shell console scripts as I came across [this page](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html). See the section "Getting the FrameworkName".